# postgresql: is it possible to run an operation that returns rows without creating a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have some sql structured as follows:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    foo text := 'thisisfoo';
    myId bigint;
BEGIN
    myId = (select id from blah.things);
    insert into bar.widgets(...)
    values (myId, foo, ...);
    select * from bar.widgets;
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

When I run this, I get:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

Things I've tried:
- changed the query to to `insert into ... returning *;` and `return select * from bar.widgets`. Both yield errors, and it looks like creating a function with a bar.widget return type is the only way forward.

Question: **Is there not a way to have a non-function use variables AND return table rows?** Reason is I don't want to add this as a function to the schema. It will only be used a few times and I don't want to clutter up the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run the `select` outside the `do` block:

```
...
END $$ language plpgsql;
select * from bar.widgets;
```

Or even rewrite it without a `do` block:

```
insert into bar.widgets(...)
values ((select id from blah.things), 'thisisfoo', ...)
returning *;
```

Comment: omg!!! i'm new to postgresql and i'm still shifting my thinking to how it works... I didn't even think of moving the select!! So simple so obvious now. lol! thank you!